# Comma Separated Integer between 1-9999 Regex

Tags: regex, string, pattern-matching

I'm struggling to come up with a regex for a list of Integers separated by a comma and ranging between 1-9999.

This is what I have so far:

```
"(^[1-9][0-9]{3}|[1-9][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9](,[1-9][0-9]{3}|[1-9][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9])*)$"
```

I don't want to allow spaces and should't end in a comma, so should only allow:

```
1,2,9999
1
43,5
```

Comment: How is this related to Objective-C or Swift?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to parse the string with `NSNumberFormatter` then check the result?

Comment: @JimmyJam Please let know if the string with the comma-separated integers can end with an LF symbol or not. Then, you can select the right answer for you.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you could have guessed that if you read the question with a patience - Jimmy is providing a regexp that works for him. So your regexp won't actually work the same way as originally correct one. The correct one is from Shadow Of.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what do you mean "better"? It simply won't match Jimmy's results :)

Answer (score 5):

An integer netween 1 and 9999 can be matched with

```
(?:[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]{1,3})
```

that is synonymic to

```
[1-9][0-9]{0,3}
```

*Details*:

- `[1-9]` - a digit from `1-9` range
- `|` - or
- `[1-9][0-9]{1,3}`  - an integer from `10` till `9999`.

or

- `[1-9]` -  a digit from `1-9` range
- `[0-9]{0,3}` - any 0 to 3 digits

So, a list of integers separated with a comma can be witten as:

```
\A(?:[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]{1,3})(?:,(?:[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]{1,3}))*\z
```

or a shorter version

```
\A[1-9][0-9]{0,3}(?:,[1-9][0-9]{0,3})*\z
```

Here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hN3tF2/3)

**Explanation**:

- `\A` - unambiguous start of the string
- `[1-9][0-9]{0,3}` - an integer regex block
- `(?:` - beginning of the non-capturing group that will match 0 or more sequences of:

  - `,` - a comma
  - `[1-9][0-9]{0,3}` - `1` till `9999` integer regex block
- `)*` - end of the non-capturing group
- `\z` - unambiguous *very* end of the string.

In Swift or Objective C string pattern, you will need to double the backslashes, like

Swift:

```
var pattern = "\\A[1-9][0-9]{0,3}(?:,[1-9][0-9]{0,3})*\\z"
```

Objective C:

```
NSString * pattern = @"\\A[1-9][0-9]{0,3}(?:,[1-9][0-9]{0,3})*\\z";
```

Since you need to *validate* strings, you need to use unambiguous anchors `\A` and `\z`. Note that `$` matches a string even if it ends with an LF symbol, thus, it is advisable to use the very end of the string anchor `\z`.

**EDIT**:

To prove those below who do not believe the Objective-C pattern above does not work, here is a [demo](https://ideone.com/uTPqbV):

```
NSString * teststr = @"1,4,566";
NSString * pattern = @"\\A[1-9][0-9]{0,3}(?:,[1-9][0-9]{0,3})*\\z";
NSPredicate * tst = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", pattern];
if ([tst evaluateWithObject:teststr]) {
   NSLog (@"yes");
}
else
{
   NSLog (@"no");
}
```

Result: `yes`

Comment: @Nekto: I always post like that. I am a hectic person. It's just me, sorry. At least I always want to provide details, alternatives, demos. Educate as much as I can. If I find another interesting fact to add, I swear I will edit it again. Oh, I seem to over-edit my comments, too :)

Comment: Btw, you still have a mistake: `NSString * pattern = @"\\A[1-9]\\d{0,3}(?:,[1-9]\\d{0,3})*\\z"` is invalid line in Objective-C ;)

Comment: OK, I will post a demo

Comment: Instead of doubting, check my update with the Objective-C demo.

Comment: Well, you added `;` in your demo. Well played.

Comment: Also using of `NSAutoreleasePool` is highly discouraged by Apple since may be 2013. Please, update your demo so the bad code isn't copy-pasted.

Comment: That part of code is what IDEONE uses automatically, I just pasted the real code into the IDEONE automatically generated samle. Blame IDEONE for that.

Comment: IDEONE? Sorry, I am not following here. But the code you posted is bad. If we forget about how you use autorelease pools, using them in this particular case is pretty much useless.

Comment: Also we aren't here to blame anyone for a bad code, right? We want to provide the best and the most correct answer =) In your case, your answer has mistakes =(

Comment: Thanks Wiktor! - "\\A[1-9][0-9]{0,3}(?:,[1-9][0-9]{0,3})*\\z" works a charm. I'm planning on using it for a swift app and hadn't thought of using NSFormatter, but your example and explanation were a great help. Thanks so much

Comment: Thank you Jimmy. These words of yours mean a lot to me, and that is what still keeps me here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my offering:

```
^[0-9]([0-9\,]{0,2}[0-9]|[0-9]{0,3})?
```

See it's matches [here](http://regexr.com/3drd8)

Comment: Hey thanks for the link for the website. It looks a great learning spot for regex bits.